# Array functions not working properly (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with the following, but the findLargest and findSmallest (as well as the findAverage, I believe) functions aren't working as they should and return incorrect values. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int findLargest(int array[], int arraySize){
int largest = array[0]; //I set the largest to the first member of the array initially
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    if (array[i] > largest){
        largest = i;
    }
}
return largest;
}

int findSmallest(int array[], int arraySize){
int smallest = array[0]; //I set the smallest to the first member of the array initially
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++ i){
    if (array[i] < smallest){
        smallest = i;
    }
 }
return smallest;
}

int findAverage(int array[], int arraySize){
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    total += array[i];
}
int average = total/arraySize;

return average;
}

void display(int array[], int arraySize){

cout << "\nThe values for the array are: \n\n";

for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    cout << array[i] << endl;
   }
}



int main(){

const int size = 50;
int taker[size];
srand(time(NULL));

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
    taker[i] = rand() % 100;  //generate 50 random numbers for the array taker
}

int largest = findLargest(taker, size);
int smallest = findSmallest(taker, size);
int average = findAverage(taker, size);

cout << "The largest entry was " << largest << endl;
cout << "The smallest entry was " << smallest << endl;
cout << "The average for all the entries is " << average << endl;

display(taker, size);

}
```

Comment: How can we know what you want it to print out if you don't say

Comment: It's rather clear... my question here pertains to the functions, they do not give me the correct values.

Comment: Is `findLargest` supposed to return the largest __value__ or __index__? You didn't say so this question isn't clear...

Comment: It is supposed to return the largest value among the random 50 values in the array. Anyway, I got my mistake now, thanks answerers... a small yet fatal overlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wish to return index.

```
int findLargest(int array[], int arraySize){
int largest = array[0]; //I set the largest to the first member of the array initially
int largestindex=0;
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    if (array[i] > largest){
        largestindex=i;
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
return largestindex;
}
```

if you wish to return value.

```
int findLargest(int array[], int arraySize){
int largest = array[0]; //I set the largest to the first member of the array initially
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    if (array[i] > largest){
        largest = array[i];
    }
}
return largest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone, very appreciated

Comment: However, one more quick question: if I wanted to return both the index and the value, would there be a "cleaner" way than having to create an almost identical function for it?

Comment: You can make a struct containing both. Or you can return them as parameters(use pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Your function for average looks good, however, for largest and smallest you need to use the value at the index rather than just the index.

Largest:

```
int findLargest(int array[], int arraySize){
   int largest = array[0]; //I set the largest to the first member of the array initially
   for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
      if (array[i] > largest){
          largest = array[i];
      }
   }
    return largest;
}
```

Smallest:

```
int findSmallest(int array[], int arraySize){
    int smallest = array[0]; //I set the smallest to the first member of the array initially
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++ i){
        if (array[i] < smallest){
           smallest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Your function for average looks good.

Answer (score 0):

In `findLargest`, you set `largest` to `i` not to `array[i]`

Answer (score 0):

you should set `smallest = array[i];largest=array[i];` in their respective functions.

Comment: Why? Could you provide more details - perhaps show how your code should be inserted, and explain why it's important?